# How to find both of data in specific array in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have saved both user's data in an array. The mongoose model is

```
var RoomSchema = new Schema({
  users: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User',
  }]
});
```

users array will hold 2 users at one time.

My goal is to query,

if User A and User B exist in the array then simply console.log("Room Exist") else if both are not in the array then simply create a new room

My current attempt.

```
router.post('/api/create-room', function(req, res, next) {
  Room.findOne({
    $and : [userA, userB]
  }, function (err, foundRoom) {
    if (foundRoom) {
      console.log('Room Already Exist');
      //return res.json('Room Already Exist');
    } else {
      var room = new Room();
      room.users.push(userA, userB);
      room.save(function(err) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        console.log('Room Created');
        //return res.json('Room created');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

The problem is that it always create a new room, meaning it couldn't find those 2 users in the room even thought I already push User A and User B in the array.

The data

[image]

Comment: Don't know if this will help but the docs use `{}` ex: $and: [ { <expression1> }, { <expression2> } .And I'm assuming you defined userA and userB properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just looking for both values to be present in the array, the use the [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) expression against the array element. This is effectively an "and" condition, applied to the same element. Just make sure `userA` and `userB` are the ObjectID values or at least valid strings:

```js
Room.findOne({ "users": { "$all": [ userA, userB ] } },function(err, foundRoom) {
    // rest of logic in here
});
```

If your intention is really to just create a new room where there is not one for that user combination, then you can really do this in a single call as follows:

```js
Room.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "users": { "$all": [ userA, userB ] } },
    { "$addToSet": { "users": { "$each": [ userA, userB ] } } },
    { "upsert": true, "new": true, "passRawResult": true },
    function(err,newRoom,raw) {
        if ( raw.value.lastErrorObject.updatedExisting == true ) {
            // Then the room was already found
        } else {
            // newRoom has the updated object data
        }
    })
)
```

So th basic case is that by using `.findOneAndUpdate()` this is now one operation. By looking at the "rawResult" from the option there, then you can tell if a new document was created or not.

The `$addToSet` makes sure that nothing new really gets added on match. But you could use `$setOnInsert` instead.

That makes more sense, since you are only talking to the database once.

Answer (score 0):

or and is wrong you just saying find a room with [userA,userB] this conditions seems to be wrong i think you have to define the field which has to be searched correctly try

```
router.post('/api/create-room', function(req, res, next) {
   Room.findOne()
    .and([
      {users: userA._id},
      {users: userB._id}
    ])
    .populate('users')
    .exec(function (err, foundRoom) {
             if (foundRoom) {
                   console.log('Room Already Exist');
                   //return res.json('Room Already Exist');
             } else {
                   var room = new Room();
                   room.users.push(userA, userB);
                   room.save(function(err) {
                   if (err) return next(err);
                           console.log('Room Created');
                   //return res.json('Room created');
             }
           })
       })
})
```